# Initialization multi texturing setup in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0

When I would like to define a texture I have to do something such as:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, dimensions.x, dimensions.y, 0,
             format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bufferImage.getData());
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

When I would like to render using that texture I would have to do:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_normal_texture_info.texture_id);
glUniform1i(m_uniformHandles.normalSampler, 1);
```

My question is if the Texture Unit has to be set in the texture loading step or it just a step done at the rendering stage. The same texture id can be rendered using different texture units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any texture unit while loading the texture. It is completely legal to bind a texture to one texture unit while loading, and then later to a different texture unit while rendering.

Note that there is always an active texture unit. So in your first code fragment, you will bind the texture to the unit that happens to be the active one (which is unit 0 by default). And if any other texture was previously bound to that texture unit, it will not be bound anymore.

Beyond that, it only matters that textures are bound to the correct unit for rendering. The critical part is that the unit the texture is bound to matches the value of the sampler uniform variable that the shader uses to sample the texture.

This is probably a typo in the question, but there is a mismatch in your code example:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_normal_texture_info.texture_id);
glUniform1i(m_uniformHandles.normalSampler, 1);
```

This would bind the texture to unit 0, and set the shader uniform to sample from unit 1. Those two values need to match. For using unit 1, the code would be:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_normal_texture_info.texture_id);
glUniform1i(m_uniformHandles.normalSampler, 1);
```

Comment: On a side note: I think OpenGL should introduce a new texture unit `GL_TEXTURE_DATA` or similar that can not be used for a sampler and which sole purpose is to be used for texture parameter setting and data specification. Also within that unit the usual texture target precedences should be dropped in favor of the target being active that was used in the most recent glBindTexture call. Since this special texture unit were not a sampling source, it would save a lot of stage management trouble.

Comment: I think that goes against Core Profile minimalistic tendency, right?